# Customized list in C#

Tags: c#, generics, inheritance, collections

I want to create customized list in c#. In my customized list I want only create customized function Add(T), other methods should remain unchanged.

When I do:

```
public class MyList<T> : List<T> {}
```

I can only overide 3 functions: `Equals`, `GetHashCode` and `ToString`.

When I do

```
public class MyList<T> : IList<T> {}
```

I have to implement all methods.

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> When I do public class MyList : IList {}
>
> I have to implement all methods.

Yes, but it's easy... just send the call to the original implementation.

```
class MyList<T> : IList<T>
{
    private List<T> list = new List<T>();

    public void Add(T item)
    {
        // your implementation here
    }
    
    // Other methods

    public void Clear() { list.Clear(); }
    // etc...
}
```

Comment: "other methods should remain unchanged": that means that in this incapsulation case you, like a developer, should map all List implementations too. Only for having one Add() customized method IMHO seems a luxury.

Answer (score 2):

You can have `MyList` to call `List<T>` implementation inetrnally, except for Add(T), you'd use [Object Composition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_composition) instead of [Class Inheritence](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inheritance_%28computer_science%29), which is also in the preface to the [GOF book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0201633612): "Favor 'object composition' over 'class inheritance'." (Gang of Four 1995:20)

Answer (score 1):

You can another thing again, by using `new` keyword:

```
public class MyList<T> : List<T> 
{
   public new void Add(T prm) 
   {
       //my custom implementation.
   }
}
```

**Bad**: The thing that you're restricted on use only of `MyList` type. Your customized `Add` will be called only if used by `MyList` object type.

**Good**: With this simple code, you done :)

Answer (score 0):

You could use the decorator pattern for this. Do something like this:

```
public class MyList<T> : IList<T>
{
    // Keep a normal list that does the job.
    private List<T> m_List = new List<T>();

    // Forward the method call to m_List.
    public Insert(int index, T t) { m_List.Insert(index, t); }

    public Add(T t)
    {
        // Your special handling.
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a `private List<T>` rather than inheritance, and implement your methods as you like.

**EDIT:** to get your `MyList` looped by `foreach`, all you want is to add `GetEnumerator()` [method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.ienumerable.getenumerator.aspx)